# How can I create a [Me] filtered view using a Lookup column with names in it?

Tags: lookup-column, column, person

Any help will be hugely appreciated as really struggling with this.
I am limited by company regulation saying I can't use code so any answer will need to be code free and not require the use of Design Manager (sorry).

I have a lookup column in a list.  The lookup information is the names of everyone in our company and the purpose of this list is to acknowledge that they have read a particular document.

I am hoping to create a [Me] view showing people what they have to acknowledge.
So far I am halfway there

View: My acknowledgements (public view)
Paremeters:

Show items only when the following is true: Acknowledgement Required from is equal to [Me]

**(This is a person or group column and this part is working fine)

And

When Column: Acknowledgement
is not equal to [Me]

**The issue with this is that the Acknowledgement column is a Lookup column. Does anyone know a work-around to make a Lookup column recognise its line items as a Person?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not possible without the use of code. As, by rights, the [ME] filter you would be adding to you calculated column only recognizes the logged in user as a "Person or Group" type. As such, wouldn't be able to ignore strings equal to the value of the User's name.

I'll assume you have a valid reason for splitting out your staff data into a separate list, but if there's anyway you could conglomerate the two, you  may have some success there.

My apologies, one of the pitfalls of SP I'm afraid

Comment: Hi George, I suspected as much. Thanks for taking the time to answer! :)