# Show items based on who is using the page

Tags: list, list-view, custom, item-level-permissions

I want to create a site which will show all relevant information for the user that is using that site. At this moment I have the idea to show an List Webpart + Contacts Web Part + Documents Webpart on that one page.

All of the documents, contacts and items of these lists have the column: 'country'. However, I would like to not have a Choice Filter. Instead, I would like to know if it is possible to have SharePoint automatically show the correct information, based on the current user's "country" value.

My idea: User "John Smith" has it's contact information in the "Contact List": including his 'country' information (e.g. USA). The information then shown on this site should be based on his country information, so the USA document, USA contacts, and USA list items.

Creating separate views for each Web Part will be a lot of work as I have 30+ different countries. So filtering would be the preferred solution.

Looking forward to your ideas

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking of classic (or on-prem) SharePoint, you can use "Current User Filter" web part, add it to page, configure, and connect to List View Web Part.

More details [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f).

Comment: Hi Jussi, I have tried to do that. Unfortunately 'country' which is the value that I want to filter on, is not part of the SharePoint profile value for current user. So using this filter will not show the correct items, documents and contacts.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible without custom code: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171183/how-can-i-create-a-me-filtered-view-using-a-lookup-column-with-names-in-it

Comment: Thanks anyway! I will try to find a different solution